# Why does my "git push" to the remote git project fail

Tags: git

I clone my git project to my U-disk.  I change a file `a.txt` of the project in my U-disk.

Then, in my project root directory of the U-disk, I run `git push`.  It notes success.
But in my `origin` project, it stays unchanged.

However, in the `origin` project root directory, when i run `git status`, it appears a change of `a.txt`.  When i run `git --hard HEAD`,  it appears my change in U-disk.

What's the matter?  How to solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is your origin project a bare repository? If not, a push to a branch that is currently checked out might lead to this kind of behavior.

Solution: Do not push to a branch that is currently checked out in the origin repository. If possible, use a bare repository as origin.

Comment: Thanks! However,for the same git repositoty ,the same operation ,why my collaborator dosen't have the problem?

Comment: This is a question that cannot be answered without looking into your and your collaborator's configuration in detail. There has to be some difference in the setups, or git wouldn't behave differently. But I still suggest to just use a bare repository as origin. If you need a repository you can work on on the machine where origin is located, you can set up a clone of origin there and configure a post-receive hook in the bare origin repository that updates the cloned repository.

Comment: Thank you very much for your detailed explanation! I have known the root of the problem. In my case ,I just need to run the code <code>git pull</code>.

Answer (score 0):

[Git-push](http://progit.org/book/ch2-5.html#pushing_to_your_remotes) pushes changes from your local repository to the remote one.

Did you forget to [commit](http://gitref.org/basic/#commit) your changed file to the local repository prior to pushing it?

Comment: I have commited .  I think the changs have been pushed to the remote one.But it has been automatically revert to its origin file.